# There are multiple root elements. Line 1, position 369

Tags: c#, xml

my c# code is

```
             var filename = "C:\\Users\\qadeer.hussain\\Desktop\\gw-msg.log";
    var xmlText = new StringBuilder();
    bool isXml = false;
    XDocument xdoc;
    foreach (var line in System.IO.File.ReadLines(filename))
    {
        if (line.Trim().StartsWith("<Message"))
            isXml = true;

        if (isXml)
        {
            xmlText.Append(line);
            if (line.Trim().EndsWith("</Message>"))
            {
               // xmlText.Clear();
                isXml = false;       
            }
        }
    }
    xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xmlText.ToString());
    xdoc.Save("C:\\Users\\qadeer.hussain\\Desktop\\gw-msg-2.log");
```

my xml file is

```
          one
          two
          three
         <Message type="sms">
        </Message>
        <Message type="sms">
         </Message>
```

it give me error too many root elements can u help me to overcome this problem
i have tried too many solution but couldn't be able to solve this problem.

Comment: Your xml file has incorrect format.

Comment: is there any solution to solve problem how can i add root element in it

Comment: my file has same kind of format

Answer (score 1):

Add root element before parsing

```
xdoc = XDocument.Parse("<root>" + xmlText.ToString() + "</root>");
```

Answer (score 1):

XML should have only one tag at root level.  XML should look like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Root>
  one
  two
  three
  <Message type="sms">
  </Message>
  <Message type="sms">
  </Message>
</Root>​
```